# Meaning of 繋ぎ合う

Tags: verbs, relative-clauses, potential-form, compounds, compound-verbs

I'm currently translating the Japanese versions of some Final Fantasy songs. I found the compound verb "**繋ぎ合えた**" in the song "Yakusoku no Basho" from FFXIII-2 as a relative clause, but the many websites I've checked for a definition came up empty. The closest I found to it is "繋ぎ合わせる."

Is 繋ぎ合う translated as "connect to/with each other," or is it the same as 繋ぐ- "to connect, join, link," etc.? Then does 繋ぎあえた　想いは永遠だから mean something like "Because the feelings that could connect each other are eternal"? I don't know if the "each other" part is necessary here since connecting already means bringing things together.

For proper context, here's the complete lyric:

> 愛よ　どうか連れていって　約束の場所へ
> 繋ぎあえた想いは永遠だから

I'm having trouble since I don't see the past potential form used much. Some translations of the form I've seen either go as "was able to" or "could/could've," but I've also seen [some translations](https://jpdb.io/conjugation/verb/%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F?expand=e#examples) where it's treated like the regular past tense form.